# child theme inherticance and php autoload

Tags: php, child-theme

I wrote this method in a parent them that will auto load a class based on the class name, thus if the class name is: SomeFolder_Folder_Folder_Class.php then it will convert that to: SomeFolder/Folder/Folder/Class.php and load it if it exists:

```
public function load_class($class){
    $path = str_replace('_', '/', $class);
    if(file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/' . $path . '.php')){
        require_once(get_template_directory() . '/' . $path . '.php');
    }
}
```

This works in conjunction with `spl_autoload_register()` to achieve this 'auto load' functionality. So instead of having a bunch of require_once you just do: `new SomeFolder_Folder_Folder_Class()` and it auto loads it.

This works great in the parent them, and even in the child theme when loading classes from the parent theme. How ever, when trying to load classes from the child theme - it fails and states it can't find said class.

So I thought lets do:

```
public function load_class($class){
    $path = str_replace('_', '/', $class);
    if(is_child_theme()){
        if(file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/' . $path . '.php')){
            require_once(get_template_directory() . '/' . $path . '.php');
        }
    }else{
        if(file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/' . $path . '.php')){
            require_once(get_template_directory() . '/' . $path . '.php');
        }
    }
}
```

But then parent theme classes start freaking out moaning they can't be found, so I added a new level of complexity:

```
public function load_class($class){
    $path = str_replace('_', '/', $class);
    if(is_child_theme()){
        if(file_exists(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $path . '.php')){
            require_once(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $path . '.php');
        }else{
            if(file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/' . $path . '.php')){
                require_once(get_template_directory() . '/' . $path . '.php');
            }
        }
    }else{
        if(file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/' . $path . '.php')){
            require_once(get_template_directory() . '/' . $path . '.php');
        }
    }
}
```

But then were back to square one where you cant find the child theme class....

So - with that said, What should  do? How do I get the auto loader to work in both the parent theme and the child theme?

Added level of complexity? child theme classes can extend and implement parent theme classes.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

use `locate_template()` instead.

```
public function load_class( $class ) 
{
    $path = str_replace('_', '/', $class);
    // returns a path when something was found
    $located = locate_template( $path, TRUE );

    return $located ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Always return `FALSE` in an autoloader if you haven’t found the class.